# Validate input on blur

Tags: javascript, jquery

I validate URLs when the user focuses out of the input field. The user gets an alert box when they enter an invalid URL. I also force `.focus()` so they have to enter a valid URL before they can proceed. The issue I have is that the alert box keeps popping and doesn't allow the user to edit their invalid URL.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/25Ld9u3d/)

```
$('.validate').blur(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var validUrl = isUrlValid($this.val());

    if (!validUrl) {
        alert('This is not a valid URL');
        $this.focus();
    }
});

function isUrlValid(url) {
    // regex match
}
```

Comment: Never alert on blur and then focus. It is setting yourself up for a loop. Add a timeout if you must or show a span instead of an alert

Comment: building on what @mplungjan said => https://jsfiddle.net/25Ld9u3d/1/

Comment: @AminJafari - try to leave the page without fixing the URL